# Creating a "copy on write" table clone in MSSQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, view

We have a production app where 99% of the actual data resides in a single table, currently about 800GB in size. We create clones (copies) of the whole database for testing and staging purposes and currently exclude this table because otherwise each cloning process would take hours instead of seconds. However, this prevents us from performing certain tests in the staging environment (final tests with production data, after all unit tests were successful, before deployment) due to missing actual data.

Is it possible to create a copy-on-write clone of a database (or single table) quickly, like a hardlink or a shadow copy but which accepts modifications (and then creates copies of the modified rows/blocks/whatever on demand) in MSSQL?

If not, is it possible to create a readonly clone of this production table inside another database (staging) on the same (or a different) DB server so that the app "thinks" this table exists, but cannot modify it, without having to duplicate 800GB of data? This would at least allow us to perform read-only data tests. I read about "CREATE SYNONYM" but this seems not to allow preventing writes.

Comment: You *appear* to be describing [database snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yes, but just for a single table. I need to be able to write to all the other tables. Snapshots are readonly for the whole database, correct?

Comment: Are you trying to make a table read-only? Your question is not clear!

Comment: I am trying to find a method to quickly (!) create a temporary clone of an 800GB production database to be able to perform final tests with production data inside a staging environment of our app. Copying the whole 800GB simply takes too long. Copy-on-write snapshots of the database would be nice, if they exist.

Comment: A snapshot is by definition copy-on write. In other words, every time a modification is made to a particular page, it has to be written to a new location in order to preserve the snapshot. It does affect the whole database though

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 says MSSQL snapshots are readonly. Am I on the wrong page in the MSSQL documentation?

Comment: The snapshot itself is read-only, yes. But the database can be written to, then quickly reverted to the snapshot. Kind of the reverse of what you are asking, but the same effect. So you create a snapshot, do whatever you want to the database, then revert the database and it's as if you restored a backup. Only it's much faster because only affected pages are restored

Comment: True, but I probably can't stop production to snapshot the database to run staging tests. :-)

Comment: Could you create the database snapshot and then create a synonym in your test DB to point to the table in the snapshot? you could then read as much as you nead but updates would fail.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem, I need to be able to update during tests. Actually, I'd be OK with only updating every table BUT the huge one. Can I copy all tables except one into a new db, and then create a (readonly) VIEW to the one 800GB data table so the app thinks it's there but cannot modify it?

Comment: Create the snapshot off your test database, then you can do what you like with your test database and be able to revert it to the snapshot. You would only need one copy of the big table, and reverting would not require the big table to be copied. Writes to that table in the test DB would still be allowed, but would disappear after revert

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to create a second copy of the 800GB. But thank you. :-)

Comment: @Jens Perhaps I misunderstood but I thought you *wanted* a read-only copy of your large table so your app code can use it in testing - creating the snapshot and a synonym pointing to the table in your cloned testing database means only that one table (the synonym) can't be updated, everything else is fine. Possibly you could create a synonym directly on the production database/table and deny update permission on the synonym?

Comment: Ideally, I could "shallow copy" the whole database, without duplicating storage as long as the contents stay the same, then migrate one copy up to the latest scheme and use it for testing, while the production instance isn't affected.
But if this is not possible, I'd be OK with copying all tables except the big one mentioned above, and creating a readonly "hardlink" of this table to the production database.